# How to select displayed columns in datagrid

Tags: compact-framework, .net-cf-3.5

I'm working on a .NET Compact Framework 3.5 app that includes a DataGrid. I've created a BindingSource using the designer and added the bindingsource as the source of the datagrid.  It automatically created columns for every suitable property of my source object type, but I don't want to display all the properties.

How do I specify which columns to display and which ones to hide?  I tried playing around with the TableStyles property of the datagrid (both in code and in designer), didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Is this for a DataGridView control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had to add the following line of code in the form's constructor, right after `InitializeComponent()`:

```
myDataGrid.TableStyles[0].MappingName = myBindingSource.GetListName(null);
```

Then I was able to change the datagrid's `TableStyles` property in order to modify the displayed columns as I please.

Answer (score 3):

That didn't work for me as the `TableStyles` collection of the `DataGrid` control was empty at the point you specify and remains so until a `DataGridTableStyle` collection is added.

Using your suggestion for setting the correct value for the `MappingName` property, I achieved the desired result by creating and adding a new `DataGridTableStyle` object containing only the public fields that were required in the `DataGrid`.

```
// Create a DataGridTableStyle to hold all the columns to be displayed in the DataGrid
DataGridTableStyle myTableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
myTableStyle.MappingName = myBindingSource.GetListName(null);  // This is the magic line
myTableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Clear();

// Add some DataGridColumnStyles
DataGridTextBoxColumn columnRowId = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
columnRowId.MappingName = "idx";  //This must match the name of the public property
ColumnRowId.HeaderText = "Record";
tableStyleReportsSummary.GridColumnStyles.Add(columnRowId);

// Add the table style to the DataGrid
myDataGrid.TableStyles.Clear();
myDataGrid.TableStyles.Add(myTableStyle);
```